# $(this.id).val() not work, the id get from classes when keypress not working, why?

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<input type="number" class="atm" id="price_1" value="0.00" />
<input type="number" class="atm" id="price_2" value="0.00" />
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {

    var input = ""; //holds current input as a string

    $(".atm").keydown(function(e) {     
        //handle backspace key
        if(e.keyCode == 8 && input.length > 0) {
            input = input.slice(0,input.length-1); //remove last digit
            $(this.id).val(formatNumber(input));
        }
        else {
            var key = getKeyValue(e.keyCode);
            if(key) {
                input += key; //add actual digit to the input string
                $(this.id).val(formatNumber(input)); //format input string and set the input box value to it
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    function getKeyValue(keyCode) {
        if(keyCode > 57) { //also check for numpad keys
            keyCode -= 48;
        }
        if(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
            return String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
        }
    }

    function formatNumber(input) {
        if(isNaN(parseFloat(input))) {
            return "0.00"; //if the input is invalid just set the value to 0.00
        }
        var num = parseFloat(input);
        return (num / 100).toFixed(2); //move the decimal up to places return a X.00 format
    }



});
```

its doesn't working, the id get from classes(atm) cannot use at all. i need someone help me to solving this problem. i'm in rush. thank you. I used console.log to check the this.id, its actually get the correct id but when do this $(this.id).val(); it does not working

Comment: why not just use `$(this)`?

Comment: Directly use `$(this).val(formatNumber(input));`

Comment: what treyBake says, but the reason your code doesn't work is because you need the hash in selectors for ids - `this.id` does not contain a hash

Comment: this refer to the class .atm, i have 2 input with .atm class

Comment: Because this.id will return a string object. Using $(this) is a good answer, but to elaborate: if you'd use $('#' + $(this.id)).val() it would work. You are attempting to resolve the element (again) by using the id.

Comment: @Leon you wouldn't wrap the `this.id` in a jquery wrapper in that selector - see yahya's answer below

Comment: @pete that's true - I was attempting to explain the *why* part, not best practise.

Comment: sorry guys, just now i figured it out, is not the problem of this.id. is the problem of the var input. two input in html shared one var input in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these options

(1)

```
$(this).val(formatNumber(input));
```

(2)

```
$("#"+this.id).val(formatNumber(input));
```

Comment: even you have many elements that have the same class, '$(this)' always refers to the one that triggered the current event

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select by ID you should use `$('#'+this.id)`.

`$(this)` this wil give you the `input` on which `keydown` event was fired.

Answer (score 0):

You are already in the corrent context, then you can use, when you are inside an event function, the following syntax:

```
$(this).val(formatNumber(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, just now i figured it out, is not the problem of this.id. is the problem of the var input. two input in html shared one var input in js

Comment: therefore, the second input always continuing the number from the previous input

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get id value.

$(this).attr('id').val();